# Cakephp 3 routing not working?

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

I have installed and setup cakephp 3 on a virtual server by ip address on port 8080. Ex. `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080`

However when I try to access an URL like `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/Users` it doesn't seems to be working.

I have the Users model, view, and controller created too.

Here is the Apache `.conf` file details:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot /var/www/productgeniycakebake/productgeniy
</VirtualHost>
```

I have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

Any one has any idea what is wrong?

Note I am able to get on to the cakephp3 main page the index but not any other subpages. It will just return 404 message.

Comment: "_Doesn't work_" is not enough information for anyone to troubleshoot your problem. Please add more details as to what _exactly_ happens (what is being shown, response code, any errors, etc..), and what _exactly_ your routes, and involved file- and classnames look like.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't redirect to a generic cakephp 404 page but just the regular 404 page we get. so routing must not be working. I followed the tutorial on the cakephp3 website.

Comment: I should have seen the 404 thingy at the end of the question... just woke up.

Comment: Please refer to the docs regarding [**URL rewriting**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#url-rewriting), have you enabled `AllowOverride` somewhere else in your config? If not then that's probably the problem.

Comment: I thought cakephp3 does not need to use URL rewriting.

Comment: OK, I enabled the URL rewrite and it is working now.

Comment: Like older CakePHP versions, 3.x can also work without URL rewriting, but of course you then won't get such pretty URLs as in your question, again [**check the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#i-can-t-use-url-rewriting), it's all explained there.

Answer (score 0):

Use this directory

```
DocumentRoot /project_name/webroot
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't 100% applicable to the content of your question but does apply to the title of the question.

Just adding this answer for anyone else who has suffered the same ordeal as me.

If you are having difficulties with CakePHP 3.0 routing make sure you disable http cache in your browser config.

The routes get cached causing them to get stuck no matter what you do to the routes.php file.

I had a hell of a time trying to get my routes to work properly before I figured this out:

In Firefox:

- In the url of firfox type in about:config
- Accept terms.
- in the search bar type: use-cache
- You should see **network.http.use-cache**
- Disable this and routes should now update every time you refresh the
  page.

Other browsers should have similar config options.

Good luck.